# Add Virtual and Simple Products to cart

Tags: cart, simple-product, virtual-products

I had developed an ecommerce site. I have both simple and virtual products in my site.so when i add simple product to cart and then i add virtual product then i am getting the following error.

```
Nominal item can be purchased standalone only. To proceed please remove other items from the quote.
```

I think we cannt add virtual and simple both at a time.

please help me how to add both to cart at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that you CAN add to cart simple products and virtual products at the same time.
What you cannot do is add to cart products with recurring profiles enabled along with ones that don't have recurring profiles disabled.

If you enabled recurring profiles by mistake for your virtual product you can change it from the backend from the Recurring Profile tab on the product edit page.

If you didn't enable it by mistake, then I guess there is no other way. Your customers will have to place 2 orders.

Comment: According to your suggestion it is not possible in magento.Thanks Marius for ypur valuable suggestion.